# Drawing a "star of david" shape

Tags: java, image

Looking to create the star of david:
 [image]

How would  I go about this in java? 
Very confused on this.

Comment: Depending on what you are drawing in, draw two triangles on top of each other with different orientations.

Comment: You could start by reading through and understanding [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) then taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
int[] xPoints = {100, 150, 200};
int[] yPoints = {100, 200, 100};

int[] yPoints2 = {175, 75, 175};

g.drawPolygon (xPoints, yPoints, 3);
g.drawPolygon (xPoints, yPoints2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with making an equilateral triangle.
2. Draw it using `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` class.
3. Then, draw another triangle, shift it down a little (this is called 'translation')
4. Then, rotate it.

Trial-and-error is the way to go :)